# Adding Custom Control to Google Map (Adding toggle for traffic layer)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add the Google Maps Traffic Layer with a control, and since I am so new with this, I cannot figure it out. I have gotten the below script from the internet with some fine tuning, but I cannot figure out how to get the control into the map. I just need a way to toggle the traffic layer on and off for the average user, so if there is a better way than to add the control to the map, I am up for anything. Thanks.

```
var map;
var chicago = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function HomeControl(controlDiv, map) {
    controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';

    var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
    controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    controlUI.style.borderWidth = '2px';
    controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
    controlUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';
    controlDiv.appendChild(conrolUI);

    var controlText = document.createElement('div');
    controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial.sans-serif';
    controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
    controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
    controlText.style.paddingRight = '4px';
    controlText.innerHTML = '<b>Home</b>';
    controlUI.appendChild(controlText);


    googlemaps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
        map.setCenter(chicago)
    });

}

function addtrafficlayer() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        maxWidth: 60,

    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);

    var homeControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var homeControl = newHomeControl(homeControlDiv, map);

    homeControlDiv.index = 1;
    map.controls(google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT).push(homeControlDiv);

    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    trafficLayer.setMap(map);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', addtrafficlayer);
```

Comment: Is your map working at all? I put the code above into a fiddle; only a gray box shows.  I just want to make sure we are at the same starting point.  Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonjonash/m8EdX/

Comment: No, it does not work now that I added the control inputs. Before, when I only had the addtrafflayer, it worked. it does not work anymore however.

Comment: Keep in mind that means in the addtrafficlayer function, you would also need to take out from the: map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv...  all the way to the last map.controls line. If you take those out along with the function above it it should work.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, your `addTrafficLayer` function actually initializes the map... twice.  This function should be named `init` or something similar instead.  Here's what should go in it:

```
function init() {
    var options = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.747688, -74.004142),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
    trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('trafficToggle'), 'click', toggleTraffic);
}
```

The `toggleTraffic` is pretty simple:

```
function toggleTraffic(){
    if(trafficLayer.getMap() == null){
        //traffic layer is disabled.. enable it
        trafficLayer.setMap(map);
    } else {
        //traffic layer is enabled.. disable it
        trafficLayer.setMap(null);             
    }
}
```

Then you just need some markup to get it going:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<button id="trafficToggle">Toggle Traffic Layer</button>
```

See this code in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonjonash/X39AV/).

Comment: I have tried to put this into my current script. Please note: I am using an Excel add-in that embeds a task pane with Google Maps inside Excel. Excel has calls from an HTML file that I am tweaking in notepad. I would post the entire script, but it is way too long. When I added the above lines, it got caught up on: [Code] google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('trafficToggle'), 'click, toggleTraffic);[/Code]

Comment: The error on that line says: Unable to get value of the property 'addEventListener': ovject is null or undefined". After that error, it gets caught up at another line in my script which it did not used to before. The line is: google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', closeinfowindow());

Comment: Works perfectly in 2/2020. Remember to declare 'var trafficLayer' with the proper scope.